# Is it possible to beat Survival Mode itemless?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

[Survival Mode](http://www.serebii.net/shuffle/survival.shtml) is a mode where you face off against 50 stages non-stop, but you select your fixed 4 Support Pokémon only before you start. From here, you play through random stages, with some stages being fixed, from the main part of the game (stages 1-150). You have a fixed amount of moves for each stage but that does increase depending on your success in the game.

As most of these fixed stages are Mega Evolutions, they are not easy to defeat without a proper strategy.

So I'm wondering: is it possible to complete all Survival Mode and the final *MegaMewtwoY* stage itemless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But the core of this strategy is **MegaBeedrill**.

First of all, you need a full-candied *MegaBeedrill* (it requires 10 MegaSpeedups).
*MegaBeedrill* really shines on stages with disruptions. It clear a 3x3 square and when full candied it megaevolves in just a match of 3 (except when an icon is in ice), and it shows is a good mega.

The rest of your team should rely on **Risk-Taker** users, with a suggested boosted Skill Level. The most powerful are:

- *Landorus-T* (Max lv 10, BP 100)
- *Hoopa Unbound* (Max lv 10, BP 100)
- *Machamp* (Max lv 20, BP 125)
- *Emboar* (Max lv 15, BP 110)

*Landorus-T* is crucial because of its effectiveness against Electric and other types, *Hoopa-U* is needed against MegaSlowbro, MegaGengar and MegaMewtwoY, the last one for the remaining coverage.

*Risk-Taker* activation rates:

> Risk-Taker (50%, 70%, 100%; Increased Damage by x1.5, x1.8, x2, x2.5)

Normally [Risk-Taker](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Skill) damage is a randomly chosen number between `BaseDamage/3` and `BaseDamage×3`, rounded down.
With a SL4 damage varies between `x1/6` and `x6`.
With a SL5 damage varies between `x1/7.5` and `x7.5`.

I would say is about using *Risk-Taker* to do huge damage, and help yourself with *Beedrill* to clear disruptions when you can't. Basically do chains starting with one or the other.
This includes support Pokemon, if you take your time you can use *Beedrill* to clean disruptions and/or make matches of support Pokemon to open a gap to *Risk-Taker*.

More info on [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonShuffle/comments/56qise/survival_mode_can_bee_cleared_itemless_now_thanks/).